# JSF ajax assigning old value to bean attribut

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using JSF2.2 and PrimeFaces 5, 
i'm trying to assign a value of a p:calendar to another p:calendar as soon as the user selects a date, 
here is part of the xhtml:

```
<p:calendar id="date1" value="#{form.date1}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" mask="true">
       <f:ajax event="select" execute="date1" render="date2"/>
</p:calendar>

<p:calendar id="date2" value="#{form.date2}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" mask="true"/>
```

and here is part of my bean:

```
public void setDate1(Date date1){
        this.date1 = date1;
        this.date2 = this.date1;//plus some more time
}
```

the only problem here, is that the date2 is always one step behind, date2 don't get the last version of date1, it always take the older value of date!

why is this happening, and how can this be fixed?

Comment: How about with p:ajax?

Comment: so i tried `<p:ajax event="click" process="date1" update="date2"/>` but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works in Primefaces 4:

```
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{testBean.updateDate2}" update="date2"/>
```

With TestBean

```
private Date date1;
private Date date2;

public void updateDate2() {
    date2 = date1;
}
// + getters/setters
```

Is your bean really named "form"? I believe you should not misuse a setter for logic like you do.